# Can we use DOM element in content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In content script, I try to use one of the follows:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
```

But none of them works! I got error: access method appendChild of null object. Can we use DOM in content script?

Comment: Two typos: `getElementByTagname` should be getElement**s**ByTag**N**ame.

Comment: If your content script runs at `document_start`, there's no `body` in the document yet so you need to wait for it using MutationObserver.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed. But nothing changed. There is still that error!

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));` works for me. That's the only line in my `contentscript.js`. The other line has a typo, as @wOxxOm said. Here's the `manifest.json` I'm using, if it helps: `{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "ex",
  "description": "ex",
  "version": "1.0",
  
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : [
        "*://*.stackoverflow.com/*"
      ],
      "js" : ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_end",
      "all_frames" : false
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}`

Comment: Yes, thank you. Problem at run_at. I specified document_start. I change to document_end. It works perfectly. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your code inside this tag:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    // your code here
});
```